# error in connection string in Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, sql

I'm working on a Visual Studio project using c# and I'm connecting it with oracle developer. I'm following a youtube toturial for this. But I'm stuck because of the connection string. in the video it was mentioned that each person has a different string. I got my string but for some reason when I pasted in the code it shows me error when I run it. (min)

this is my connection string:

```
Data Source = xe; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = wejdan; Password = ***********; Unicode = True
```

in this code:

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source = xe; Persist Security Info = True; User ID = wejdan; Password = ***********; Unicode = True");
            con.Open();
            string newcom = "select username from login where username='"+textBox1.Text+"'and password='"+textBox2.Text+"'";
            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(newcom, con);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            adp.Fill(ds);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
```

it shows that "Unicode" is wrong and when I remove `con.Open();` then it throws the error.

here is the [Link to the video](https://youtu.be/8PKSs_HMXww?t=7m55s)

can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't think that you need to specify the encoding like that. For connection string help you can use the resource https://www.connectionstrings.com/ to find out what parameters you need to include.

As an aside that video looks to be very outdated and the code is introducing SQL injection vulnerabilities.